How to bundle external dependencies to my javascript file with rollup
Overview:
I am writing a plugin in typescript with the aim of supporting as many browsers as possible. It will be served from the CDN via a single script tag.
I am using Rollup as a bundler, with @babel/preset-env.
{
input: "./src/plugin/index.ts",
output: [
  {
    dir: "build",
    format: "system",
  }
],
plugins: [
  typescript({
    tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'
  }), 
  resolve(), 
  nodePolyfills(), 
  babel({ 
    babelHelpers: 'bundled' 
  }),
  terser({
    format: {
      comments: false,
    },
    compress: {
      drop_console: true,
    }
  }),
]},


Is it true that I need to generate a system module file for the best possible browser compatibility?

If yes, how could I possibly bundle this system.js and needed polyfill into my plugin in a specific order?


Polyfills needed in specific order:
<script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/src/entrypoints/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>    
<script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/src/entrypoints/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

I have tried so far:
I have tried importing the system.js at the top of my index.js file and it seems to be bundled in but when I run it the browser I get system js not defined error.
I was I am trying to achieve a valid solution or there is a better solution like dynamically loading everything from CDN? I don't want to end up with massive bundle :(
Thanks
